# Differential equation: what's the meaning of this writing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

The differential equation solution is a function defined in a range $I$ so that replaced by $x$ returns an identity. The function

$\varphi = \varphi (t)$

is solution if

$F(t,\varphi,\varphi^{'},\varphi^{''},...,\varphi^{(n)}) = 0$

What's the meaning of the last equation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For instance, the Bessel equation $$ x^2 y'' + x y' + (x^2 - \alpha^2) y = 0 $$ can be written in the form $F(x, y, y', y'') = 0$ where $F$ is a function of four variables defined by $$ F(x, y_0, y_1, y_2) = x^2 y_2 + x y_1 + (x^2-\alpha^2)y_0. $$

Comment: $F(t, \phi, \phi', \phi'', \cdots, \phi^{(n)})$ is a functional. It takes as input a function $\phi(t)$ and its derivatives and returns a real/complex number as output.